# How can I exclude a specific file from being translated to AMD modules with Babel

Tags: javascript, amd, babeljs

I'm using Babel to translate my JavaScript files from ES6 to ES5 using AMD modules. While 95% of the files in my project use AMD, I have a few standalone files that are loaded in directly that I would prefer to exclude from being converted to modules.

Is there an easy way to exclude files using Babel 5 (I would accept a Babel 6 only answer if necessary)?   I would prefer an answer that was configured in the file itself rather than in a config file, so it was obvious to people reading the file that it was not being converted to AMD.